# Defining a typescript object and specifying optional element

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a type script class which has a property like so

```
pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, icon: any}>
```

How can i make the `icon` part of the array optional? so that this would be a valid value

```
this.pages = [
        { title: 'Dashboard', component: Page1, icon: 'clipboard' },
        { title: 'Page dos', component: Page2 },
        { title: 'Page dos', component: Page2 }
];
```

I am very new to typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use question mark for optional property:

```
pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, icon?: any}>
```